# Can not install mysqli in Centos

Tags: php, linux, mysqli, centos6

I can not install the Mysqli.

I am using Centos 6 , apache 2.2.x and php 5.4 MySql 5.5.37-cll

I tried:

```bash
yum install php-pdo php-mysqli
```

and I see:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.clouvider.net
 * elrepo: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: centos.hyve.com
 * updates: mirrors.coreix.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php-pdo available.
No package php-mysqli available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I tried :

```bash
yum install php-mysqli
```

and I see :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.openitc.uk
 * elrepo: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: centos.hyve.com
 * updates: mirrors.coreix.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mysqli available.
```

In my php.ini in section Dynamic Extensions I have none module installed ( i think. ) Correct me if I am wrong.
php.ini - > Dynamic Extensions

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;  
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following  
; syntax:  
;  
;   extension=modulename.extension  
;  
; For example, on Windows:  
;  
;   extension=msql.dll  
;  
; ... or under UNIX:  
;  
;   extension=msql.so  
;  
; Note that it should be the name of the module only; no directory information   
; needs to go here.  Specify the location of the extension with the  
; extension_dir directive above.  


;Windows Extensions  
;Note that MySQL and ODBC support is now built in, so no dll is needed for it.  
;  
;extension=php_bz2.dll  
;extension=php_cpdf.dll  
;extension=php_crack.dll  
;extension=php_curl.dll  
;extension=php_db.dll  
;extension=php_dba.dll  
;extension=php_dbase.dll  
;extension=php_dbx.dll  
;extension=php_domxml.dll  
;extension=php_exif.dll  
;extension=php_fdf.dll  
;extension=php_filepro.dll  
;extension=php_gd2.dll  
;extension=php_gettext.dll  
;extension=php_hyperwave.dll  
;extension=php_iconv.dll  
;extension=php_ifx.dll  
;extension=php_iisfunc.dll  
;extension=php_imap.dll  
;extension=php_interbase.dll  
;extension=php_java.dll  
;extension=php_ldap.dll  
;extension=php_mbstring.dll  
;extension=php_mcrypt.dll  
;extension=php_mhash.dll  
;extension=php_mime_magic.dll  
;extension=php_ming.dll  
;extension=php_mssql.dll  
;extension=php_msql.dll  
;extension=php_oci8.dll  
;extension=php_openssl.dll  
;extension=php_oracle.dll  
;extension=php_pdf.dll  
;extension=php_pgsql.dll  
;extension=php_printer.dll  
;extension=php_shmop.dll  
;extension=php_snmp.dll  
;extension=php_sockets.dll  
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll  
;extension=php_w32api.dll  
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll  
;extension=php_xslt.dll  
;extension=php_yaz.dll  
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

By the way, all the above module is for windows, Should I need to edit/activate any module for the Centos? I need mysql and mysqli connections to database.

---

**Update**

I rebuild the apache with easyapache and I check the mysqli extension. I'll post the results from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the results you posted above, it's not installing because it can't find the php-pdo package in any of the repositories configured on your server. It looks like you have made changes to your repositories as `elrepo` is not in either the version 5 or 6 distributions that I have installed.

I would suggest you first list the packages availabe in these repositories as they may be packaged under a different name. Run `yum list php*` to see an output of php packages. Yum will then tell you what is available, installed, and needs updating.

Note: If you're on a shared host, chances are that PHP is already installed and mapped to a specific version. Often times, you'll see the version number in the package name, so php might be a php4 install, php5 might be a php version 5.2 and below install, php53 might be a php version 5.3 install, and yes I've even seen a php6 package mapped to php version 5.3. So it wouldn't be out of the ordinary if the PHP package installed on YOUR server includes a version number in the package name. Really depends on what repositories you're setup to use.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for others, make sure your /etc/yum.conf exclude= line is commented out.