# How to install php-mysqli package for Cent OS

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, centos, cpanel

I am installing mysqli but it is not getting installed every time i type the following command:

> yum install php-mysqli  I get the following message:

```
Loaded plugins : fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
*base : mirrors.XXXXX.com
*extras: mirrors.XXXXX.com
*updates : mirrors.XXXXX.com
No package php-mysqli available
Error : Nothing to do
```

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834031/can-not-install-mysqli-in-centos). Solve your problem.

Comment: Virendra- From where i will get the php-pdo package so that i can install it from command line, Can u please give me full description

Comment: running yum list php* - No matching package to list

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320644/how-do-i-enable-pdo-using-centos). and [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747136/how-do-i-configure-php-to-enable-pdo-and-include-mysqli-on-centos).

Comment: I tried, after running it gives error messeage ERROR : 'make' failed

Comment: My problem did'nt solved after writing if (!extension_loaded('pdo')) 
{    dl('pdo.so'); } too.

Comment: Do you have any hosting control panel on this server?

Comment: I have cpanel installed on this server

Comment: Are you using cPanel on your server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed cPanel on your server then you will have to install php-mysqli modules on your server through easyapache scripts. You can install it through WHM OR SSH

WHM >> Software >> EasyApache and follow instruction

And through SSH, Please try with the following command

```
/scripts/easyapache
```

Comment: Thanks 24x7servermanagement i have installed as in your answer but i am getting following error -message Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in ------.